# JAVA API http server - get url parameters and stop server

Tags: java, api, httpserver

I'm playing with this http server example and I have to questions:

1) instead of this static answer string "Hello world", I would like to change the string with the word of the URL. So if I type `http://localhost:8004/example` and reload the page it should show `example`.

2) How can I stop the server? Because it always says that the port is already bound if I try again.

Does someone has an idea?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

/*
 * a simple static http server
*/
public class SimpleHttpServer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8004), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();
  }

  static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
      String response = "Hello world";
      t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
      OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
      os.write(response.getBytes());
      os.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You start the server, then the main method terminates, leaving the server in its background thread, continuing to occupy the port. You need to wait until some event, such as the main thread being interrupted, and stop the server. Also, you can obtain the path component of the request URI using t.getRequestURI().getPath().

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class SimpleHttpServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8004), 0);
    server.createContext("/test", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
    server.start();

    try
    {
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
            Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        server.stop(0);
    }
  }
  static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
      String response = t.getRequestURI().getPath();
      t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
      OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
      os.write(response.getBytes());
      os.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an error with your code: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 HttpServer cannot be resolved to a type
 HttpServer cannot be resolved
 InetSocketAddress cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You need to include them!